# Непоследовательные и необязательные группы захвата

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Каким образом в регулярных выражениях определяются необязательные и, что более важнее, непоследовательные группы захвата?

Объясню на примере. Предположим, что у нас есть некоторые строки, например из log-файла, которые обрабатываются с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
01.01.2021 - 00:00:00 TRACE part is created
01.01.2021 - 00:00:00 TRACE part.id=42
01.01.2021 - 01:10:11 TRACE part.id=11, order.id=1
02.02.2022 - 02:20:22 DEBUG Part with id 2 added to Order 22
03.03.2023 - 03:30:33 INFO Order (id=3, part.id=33) is generated
04.04.2024 - 04:40:44 WARN Can't find part 4
05.05.2025 - 05:50:55 ERROR Order 5 cannot be created because a part is missing
```

То есть, дата-время, далее один из пяти предопределённых уровней логирования и через пробел сообщение. В строках имеются записи об order и part, которые нас интересуют. Как видно, в некоторых сообщениях сначала идёт part и затем order, но в некоторых строках наоборот. Нас интересуют только те сообщения, где после order или part через некоторое количество символов идёт число, которое с ним ассоциируется.

Если я использую следующее выражение:

```
/^(?<dateTime>.+) (?<level>(?:TRACE|DEBUG|INFO|WARN|ERROR)).*(?:part[^0-9]+(?<part>[0-9]+)?).*(?:order[^0-9]+(?<order>[0-9]+)).*$/gmi

Match 1: 01.01.2021 - 01:10:11 TRACE part.id=11, order.id=1
dateTime: 01.01.2021 - 01:10:11
level: TRACE
part: 11
order: 1


Match 2: 02.02.2022 - 02:20:22 DEBUG Part with id 2 added to Order 22
dateTime: 02.02.2022 - 02:20:22
level: DEBUG
part: 2
order: 22
```

, то получаю совпадения для тех строк, где part и order определены в том-же порядке, как и в регулярном выражении. Если же указываю квантификатор `?` для группы захвата part (0 или один раз), то строки `Order (id=3, part.id=33) is generated` и `Order 5 cannot be created because a part is missing` также попадают в группу захвата order. Если же указать квантификатор `?` для группы захвата order, то в группы захвата order и part вообще ничего не попадает, они как будто пропускаются. Если использовать pipe-символ, например так:

```
(?:(?:part[^0-9]+(?<part>[0-9]+)?)|(?:order[^0-9]+(?<order>[0-9]+)))
```

, то в группу захвата попадает только одно значение: либо order, либо part.

**Каким образом в регулярном выражении определить необязательные группы захвата в произвольном порядке при их наличии в строке не более одного раза?**

---

Поиграться с выражением [можно здесь](https://regex101.com/r/FCKNUn/1).

Comment: так и написали бы `(order... part | part ... order)`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aJ36dB/1 вроде такого

Comment: @teran Правильно ли я понимаю, что при таком подходе нужно будет указывать все возможные комбинации? Т.е. при необходимости использовать три группы возможных вариантов будет уже куда больше. Для большего количества групп регулярное выражение будет очень монструозным. Помимо этого в предложенный вариант не решает проблему "необязательности" наличия групп, т.е. 2, 6 и 7 строка не попадают в группы.

Comment: Может, так `^(?<dateTime>\S+\s*-\s*\S+) (?<level>TRACE|DEBUG|INFO|WARN|ERROR)(?=.*part[^0-9]+(?<part>[0-9]+)?)?(?=.*order[^0-9]+(?<order>[0-9]+))?`? https://regex101.com/r/FCKNUn/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew большое спасибо за подсказку possitive lookahead! [Посмотрите](https://regex101.com/r/bvV5Ax/6) почти получилось:) Теперь единственная проблема, что при отсутствии цифры для соответствующей группы, но её наличия у последующей, обе группы ассоциируются с одним и тем-же числом (например как в 1 и 6 строке). Но, мне кажется, что это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря [teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499065/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0#comment2688191_1499065) и [WiktorStribiżew](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499065/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0#comment2688497_1499065) было найдено решение с использованием положительных опережающих проверок *(positive lookahead)*. Помимо этого пришлось "оборачивать" каждую группу в долнительные скобки, т.к. при использовании `?=` не получается указать квантификатор `?` для группы:

```java
var regex = "^"
    + "(?<dateTime>.{19}) "
    + "(?<level>[a-z]+) .*?"
    + "(?:(?=.*?message.+?(?<msg>[0-9]+)))?.*?"
    + "(?:(?=.*?part.+?(?<part>[0-9]+)))?.*?"
    + "(?:(?=.*?order.+?(?<order>[0-9]+)))?.*?"
    + "$";
```

[*Пример работы*](https://regex101.com/r/bvV5Ax/7)

Это решило проблему несоответствия следования групп в выражении и строке, но как видно из примера работы осталась проблема захвата разными группами одного числа при отсутствии оного для предыдущей группы. Например, в первой строке представленного примера, группы *part* и *message* захватывают одно и то-же число, так как для группы *part* соответствующее число отсутствует.