# Как исключить наложение групп захвата в регулярном выражении?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Имеется следующее регулярное выражение:

```java
var regex = "^.*?"
          + "(?:(?=.*?message.+?(?<msg>[0-9]+)))?"
          + ".*?"
          + "(?:(?=.*?part.+?(?<part>[0-9]+)))?"
          + ".*?"
          + "(?:(?=.*?order.+?(?<order>[0-9]+)))?"
          + ".*?$";
```

И строки, которые обрабатываются этим выражением:

```
abc part is created (message 42)
abc (message 42) part.id=24
abc order.id=123, (message 42) part.id=321
[message 42] Part with id 34 added to Order 22
abc Order (id=3, part.id=56) is generated "message 42"
Can't create order, becasue part 4 not found
Order 5 cannot be created because a part is missing
```

То есть какое-то ключевое слово (в приведённом примере *part*, *order* и *message*), а затем число, которое ассоциируется/захватывается соответствующей группой. Важно то, что выражение позволяет захватывать группы вне зависимости от их положения в строке.

Проблема в том, что при отсутствии числа у первой группы число "захватывается" у следующей. В примере выше это происходит:

- в первой строке, где группы part и message захватывают одно и то-же число 42;
- в предпоследней, где группы order и part захватывают одно и то-же число 4;

Каким образом можно исключить наложение групп? Внедрить каким-то образом негативные/позитивные опережающие/ретроспективные проверки?

---

- [*Пример работы выражения на regex101*](https://regex101.com/r/bvV5Ax/10)
- [*Предыстория вопроса*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499065)

Comment: определенно что между именем и числом не должно быть другого имени(имен) поэтому да их нужно исключать, в третьей снизу `Order 3`?

Comment: извлеките из строки все ключевые слова и все числа в список. Из списка обрабатывайте соседние пары вида ключевое слово/число. Так проще. `(part|order|message|[0-9]+)`.

Comment: хорошее решение, главное сохранить порядок

Comment: @DaniilLoban, видимо "Part with id 34" тоже должно обрабатываться.

Comment: ну с 4 снизу все как-то более менее ясно, вообще конечно не плохо бы знать общие возможные случаи, пока ручной разбор и вправду выглядит проще

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я не могу обрабатывать что-то позже. Есть API, которое принимает регулярное выражение с именованными группами, которые используются для преобразования строки к табличному представлению (пары "ключ-значение"). Другими словами, я не могу использовать одну группу со всеми возможными ключевыми словами, т.к. эта группа будет иметь одно и тоже имя в результате Map<String, String>.

Comment: @DaniilLoban "... выражение позволяет захватывать группы вне зависимости от их положения в строке." Порядок следования групп в строке произвольный.

Comment: Обратитесь к этому API, извлеките целиком строки в виде одного столбца. Обработайте их у себя как вам удобно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy повторю ещё раз: я пользователь этого API и моя проблема в составлении регулярного выражения. При вызове API с выражением данные результата работы в табличном виде (где столбцы - это имена групп в выражении) уходят далее и обработать их никоим образом не представляется возможным.

Answer (score 0):

Если вербализировать ту идею которую подал [@Stanislav Volodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/416121/stanislav-volodarskiy) то получится примерно такой код возвращающий в данном случае массив массивов где подмасив состоит из ключевого слова и значения:

```js
const strings = [
"abc part is created (message 42)",
"abc (message 42) part.id=24",
"abc order.id=123, 5 (message 42) 5 part.id=321 5",
"[message 42] Part with id 34 added to Order 22",
"abc Order (id=3, part.id=56) is generated \"message 42\"",
"Can't create order, becasue part 4 not found",
"Order 5 cannot be created because a part is missing"]

for (const str of strings){
    const temp = []
    for (const spart of str.matchAll(/part|message|order|[0-9]+/gi)){
      temp.push(spart) //собираем только те части которые нам интересны
    }
    const merge = temp.join(' ').toLowerCase() // стандартизируем вывод
    console.log(
       Array.from(merge.matchAll(/(?<name>\w+)\s(?<val>\d+)/g))
         .map(e => (Object.values({...e.groups}))) // создаем подмасивы из пар 
         .toString() // для компактного вывода [[k1, v1], [k2, v2], ...]
    )
}
```

Для компактности вывода в консоли сниппета пришлось пожертвовать квадратными скобками

```
[ [ 'message', '42' ] ]
[ [ 'message', '42' ], [ 'part', '24' ] ]
[ [ 'order', '123' ], [ 'message', '42' ], [ 'part', '321' ] ]
[ [ 'message', '42' ], [ 'part', '34' ], [ 'order', '22' ] ]
[ [ 'order', '3' ], [ 'part', '56' ], [ 'message', '42' ] ]
[ [ 'part', '4' ] ]
[ [ 'order', '5' ] ]
```

*В третью строку я специально добавил три 5 чтобы посмотреть на корректность работы алгоритма*

**Вариант через регулярку** (нужна донастройка)

Основная идея - использовать негативный просмотр `?!`,
Указываем какие группы мы не ожидаем в этом месте `(?!.*order.*)|(?!.*part.*)`

Код:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //final String regex = "^.*?(?:(?=.*?message.+?(?<msg>[0-9]+)))?.*?(?:(?=.*?part.+?(?<part>[0-9]+)))?.*?(?:(?=.*?order.+?(?<order>[0-9]+)))?.*?$";
        
        final String regex = "^.*?(?:(?=.*?message(?:(?!.*order.*)|(?!.*part.*)|(?:[.]id=|[ ]))(?<msg>[0-9]+)))?"
         + ".*?(?:(?=.*?part(?:(?!.*order.*)|(?!.*message.*)|(?:[.]id=|[ ]))(?<part>[0-9]+)))?"
         + ".*?(?:(?=.*?order(?:(?!.*part.*)|(?!.*message.*)|(?:[.]id=|[ ]))(?<order>[0-9]+)))?.*?$";
        
        final String string = "abc part is created (message 42)\n"
             + "abc (message 42) part.id=24\n"
             + "abc order.id=123, (message 42) part.id=321\n"
             + "[message 42] Part with id 34 added to Order 22\n"
             + "abc Order (id=3, part.id=56) is generated \"message 42\"\n"
             + "Can't create order, becasue part 4 not found\n"
             + "Order 5 cannot be created because a part is missing";
        
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            System.out.println("Group message" + ": " + matcher.group("msg"));
            System.out.println("Group part" + ": " + matcher.group("part"));
            System.out.println("Group order" + ": " + matcher.group("order"));
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Full match: abc part is created (message 42)
Group message: 42
Group part: null
Group order: null

Full match: abc (message 42) part.id=24
Group message: 42
Group part: 24
Group order: null

Full match: abc order.id=123, (message 42) part.id=321
Group message: 42
Group part: 321
Group order: 123

Full match: [message 42] Part with id 34 added to Order 22
Group message: 42
Group part: null // нужно доработать регулярку для with id
Group order: 22

Full match: abc Order (id=3, part.id=56) is generated "message 42"
Group message: 42
Group part: 56
Group order: null // нужно доработать регулярку для (id=3

Full match: Can't create order, becasue part 4 not found
Group message: null
Group part: 4
Group order: null

Full match: Order 5 cannot be created because a part is missing
Group message: null
Group part: null
Group order: 5
```

Пример доработки регулярки для конкретных случаев:

- для `Part with id` будет `| with id |`
- для `Order (id=3` будет `| \\(id=|`  экранируем скобку

Вся регулярка:

```
     final String regex = "^.*?(?:(?=.*?message(?:(?!.*order.*)|(?!.*part.*)|(?:[.]id=| with id | \\(id=|[ ]))(?<msg>[0-9]+)))?"
 + ".*?(?:(?=.*?part(?:(?!.*order.*)|(?!.*message.*)|(?:[.]id=| with id | \\(id=|[ ]))(?<part>[0-9]+)))?"
 + ".*?(?:(?=.*?order(?:(?!.*part.*)|(?!.*message.*)|(?:[.]id=| with id | \\(id=|[ ]))(?<order>[0-9]+)))?.*?$";
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но необходимо решить всё одним регулярным выражением, .т.е. без последующей обработки результатов.

Comment: @XelaNimed, если вопрос связан как Вы писали выше с API можно подготовить строки для этого почти не нужно менять код дополню ответ.

Comment: @XelaNimed если Вы напишите чуть больше своего кода в вопросе, а именно меня интересует момент от получения данных до передачи из API (т.е. применение регулярки и отправка), я смогу дать более подходящий ответ.

Comment: Тут не нужен код - вопрос касается только регулярного выражения. Конечно при обработке/подготовке файлов своим кодом эта проблема отпадает сама собой, т.к. в этом случае никакие регулярные выражения не нужны, но для регулярок инфраструктура уже есть. Просто не хочу "пилить" для этого отдельный сервис, встраивать его затем в весь бизнес-процесс и т.д..

Comment: @XelaNimed обновил ответ, но нужно еще доразбираться

Comment: Понятное дело если будут случаи не перечисленные в данном наборе строк придется снова править регулярку, лично я все же склоняюсь к первому варианту по простоте работы с кодом, но если второй вариант устроит я тоже буду рад.